# Function template argument deduction failed using std::optional

Tags: c++, templates, option-type, generic-programming

I would like to write a template function taking an optional argument using `std::optional`,

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void fcn(T1 v1, std::optional<T2> v2)
{
}

int main()
{
    fcn(1, 1);            // failed to compile
    fcn(1, std::nullopt); // failed as well
}
```

However, the compiler can't deduce `T2` for neither cases.

I understand that there's a trick when `T1` and `T2` are the same by putting the second argument into a non-deducible context like,

```
template<typename T>
void fcn(T v1,
         std::enable_if<true, T>::type v2) 
{
}
```

So that the caller can call `fcn(1, 1)` normally. And my first question is how to achieve this for my previous example without forcing the caller to write `fcn(v1, std::make_optional(v2))`?

And my second question is how to call `fcn` using `std::nullopt` other than writing function overloads? Since in my use case there might be several optional arguments and writing all the permutation of overloads will be too impractical.

----EDIT----

As the comments suggest, there are multiple ways to make the code compile, but none is as intuitive as a normal function call. Maybe a further question to ask is what is the proper way to write template functions taking in optional arguments with different types?

Comment: Just as a remark, this forces the caller to write `fcn<int, int>(1, 1)` or `fcn<int, int>(1, std::nullopt)`, which seems more reasonable than `fcn(v1, std::make_optional(v2))`.

Comment: @YSC But I think it's still not very intuitive to let caller provide the second type parameter although she intents to omit it.

Comment: @unclejimbo: if you have no use for knowledge of the type `T2` - such that you'd be equally happy to have the argument omitted - then you could provide a default value for the `T2` parameter that you know lets your code compile.  That doesn't scale that well though: you can only omit arguments when there are no later arguments you want to specify, unless you use some hackery to simulate named arguments (google if interested).  If you've some interest in the type, the caller will have to specify it (as in my answer).

Comment: Which function call do you expect from `fcn(1, std::nullopt);` ? any `T2` would be valid (as long it is valid for `optional`)

Answer (score 1):

> how to achieve this for my previous example without forcing the caller to write fcn(v1, std::make_optional(v2))?

You can do it by separating the deduction part from the use of `std::optional`.

> how to call fcn using std::nullopt other than writing function overloads?

You can add one templated overloading, which will deal with all `std::nullopt` cases. For this one, you need to specify the template argument for that optional. It's not a problem, because you can change the order of 2 template parameters.

```
template<typename T2, typename T1>
void fcn_impl(T1 v1, std::optional<T2> v2) {}

template<typename T2, typename T1>
void fcn(T1&& v1, T2&& v2)
{
    fcn_impl(std::forward<T1>(v1),
            std::make_optional(std::forward<T2>(v2)));
}

template<class T2, class T1>
void fcn(T1&& v1)
{
    fcn_impl<T2>(std::forward<T1>(v1), std::nullopt);
}

int main()
{
    // call the first one
    fcn(1, 1);

    // call std::nullopt one
    fcn<short>(1); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> And my first question is how to achieve this for my previous example without forcing the caller to write fcn(v1, std::make_optional(v2))

You might use extra indirection (as shown by liliscent), but for `std::null_opt`, you would have to specify the type...

> As the comments suggest, there are multiple ways to make the code compile, but none is as intuitive as a normal function call. Maybe a further question to ask is what is the proper way to write template functions taking in optional arguments with different types?

One easy way is overloads:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void fcn(T1 v1, T2 v2)
{
}

template<typename T1>
void fcn(T1 v1)
{
}
```

An alternative would be to check inside the function the given type

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void fcn(T1 v1, T2 v2, T3 v3)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<std::nullopt_t, T2>::value) {
    // ...
    }
    if constexpr (std::is_same<std::nullopt_t, T3>::value) {
    // ...
    }
}
```

A more complicated way would be variadic template:

```
template<typename T1, typename ... Ts>
void fcn(T1 v1, Ts&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) == 0) {
        // ...
    } else /*if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) == 1)*/ {
        auto& v2 = std::get<0>(std::tie(args));
        // ...
    }
}
```